# Trying to use packages in Jupyter notebook (.ipynb)

Tags: packages

I am trying to use the package `actuarialsymbol` to get out: `$\ax{\angln}$`. But I am having trouble trying to get this work.

I am able to get this out on a standard .tex document but for both .md and .ipynb, I only get the following error:

```
ParseError: KaTeX parse error: Undefined control sequence: \ax at pos1: \ax{\angln}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, md and ynb are not real TeX engines that load and process arbitrary TeX code, but they interpret a subset of macros on their own (using e.g. MathJax), with `\ax` probably not among them. So this means that you can use TeX-like syntax to write simple texts, but will not be able to process full TeX code.

Comment: Welp, if itt's not possible looks like I'll have to use pandoc to convert to .tex first